# handlebars.js doesnt render document

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I ve got a problem with handlebars.js. perhaps it is totally trivial but i am also totally new in handlebars. So...here is sample code in my index.html which goes like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
        <head>

            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
            <title></title>

            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
            <script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
            <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <script src="scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>


            <script src='scripts/content.js'></script>
            <script src='scripts/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.4.js'></script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
            <script src="scripts/plugins.js"></script>
            <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>


        </head>

        <body>

            <!--[if lt IE 7]>
                <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
            <![endif]-->

            <!-- Add your site or application content here -->

<script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>Real Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {{#users}}
            <tr>
              <td>{{username}}</td>
              <td>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</td>
              <td>{{email}}</td>
            </tr>
          {{/users}}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </script>


        </body>
    </html>
```

And there is also this content.js file which contains simple javascript code but it still doesnt work. If any of you could advise or give solution i'd be very thankful. Thank you in advance

```
 var source   = $("#some-template").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var data = { users: [
      {username: "alan", firstName: "Alan", lastName: "Johnson", email: "alan@test.com" },
      {username: "allison", firstName: "Allison", lastName: "House", email: "allison@test.com" },
      {username: "ryan", firstName: "Ryan", lastName: "Carson", email: "ryan@test.com" }
    ]};
  $("#content-placeholder").html(template(data));
```

Best regards

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't work"?  Are the errors reported in the browser console?  Does *anything* happen? What have you done so far to debug the problem?

Comment: The content kept in the content.js should be rendered on the screen, but actually nothing happens, the screen is totally white without any data.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you created a custom block helper iterator called "users" then the following block will not execute which would be why nothing is visible when you attempt to render your template.

#### Incorrect Block Helper Iterator:

```
{{#users}}
   ...
{{/users}}
```

Based on the data you gave in your example you should do the following:

#### Correct Block Helper Iterator:

```
{{#each user}}
   My name is {{this.firstname}} {{this.lastname}} and my email is {{this.email}}.
{{/each}}
```

You can reference block helpers on the [Handlebarsjs](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html) documentation site. It might be a little challenging to digest at first, but play around a bit and you will start to learn some of the Handlebarsjs features.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're importing your "content.js" script *before* you import jQuery.
2. The code in that script should be wrapped in a jQuery "ready" handler:

   ```
    $(function() {
       var source   = $("#some-template").html();
       var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
       var data = { users: [
         {username: "alan", firstName: "Alan", lastName: "Johnson", email: "alan@test.com" },
         {username: "allison", firstName: "Allison", lastName: "House", email: "allison@test.com" },
         {username: "ryan", firstName: "Ryan", lastName: "Carson", email: "ryan@test.com" }
       ]};
       $("#content-placeholder").html(template(data));
    });
   ```

The first problem would cause an error to be logged in your browser's console. That's something you should *always* check first.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but it doesnt function either. I moved the content.js after jquery file and put the whole content.js inside the ready handler. really have no idea what's wrong...but it's still only javascript file so it should run normally in the browser...or...it requires server-side programming ?

Comment: @HermanCodelove have you checked for errors in the console?  Have you added some `console.log()` calls to make sure that your code is even being called successfully?

Comment: There is an error displayed in the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token - That's all.

Comment: @HermanCodelove that sounds like it could be a hidden special character somewhere in your code. That can happen sometimes when you cut and paste code from jsfiddle or some other online editing environments.  It can be tricky to find such problems.

Comment: Yes, I found that bug, but it was caused by main.js. I have deleted the file but it still doesnt work...HANDLEBARS Y U NO RENDER ?! :D

Comment: Well add some `console.log()` calls to that code to make sure it's running.

Comment: could you please instruct me how to do this. I am not js expert so to speak ;)

Comment: Just add `console.log("ADDING TEMPLATE NOW");` or something to your function, and then check the browser debug console.